# pandas aggregate column values after two levels of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 columns.

- time as DateTimeIndex type
- signalid as int type
- intensity as float type
- eventcount as integer type

Time value is ascending but with irregular interval. I need separate signals to columns in dataframe and resample the intensities of each signal with fixed interval for cross correlation calculation. The resampled intensity is simply the last recorded value of that signal (may use interpolation later). The event count is the sum of all events within that interval.

I group the captured signal samples by signal id and then using grouper to group samples of each signal to time intervals. after getting resample data, I concatenate intensities into dataframe again.

```
dfg = df.groupby('signalid')
signals_list = {g: dfg.get_group(g).groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='100ms')).agg({'intensity' : 'last', 'eventcount' : np.sum}) for g in dfg.groups}
intensity_list = [v['intensity'].to_frame(k) for k,v in signals_list.items()]
intensity_df = pd.concat(intensity_list).fillna(method='ffill')

event_list = [v['eventcount'].to_frame(k) for k,v in signals_list.items()]
event_df = pd.concat(event_list)
```

Is there neater method to do this without converting it to list of series?

Here is part of the source data frame:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
d = {'time': {0: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803606'),
  1: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803611'),
  2: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803607'),
  3: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803614'),
  4: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803609'),
  5: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803617'),
  6: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803616'),
  7: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.803621'),
  8: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.813251'),
  9: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:29.813253'),
  10: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.376274'),
  11: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.376275'),
  12: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.386322'),
  13: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.386323'),
  14: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.386325'),
  15: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.386327'),
  16: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.407347'),
  17: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.407346'),
  18: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.492530'),
  19: Timestamp('2018-10-23 06:09:30.492532')},
 'signalid': {0: 1299,
  1: 1299,
  2: 1299,
  3: 1299,
  4: 1299,
  5: 1299,
  6: 1299,
  7: 1299,
  8: 27,
  9: 27,
  10: 1299,
  11: 1299,
  12: 1177,
  13: 1177,
  14: 1177,
  15: 1177,
  16: 5,
  17: 5,
  18: 2628,
  19: 2628},
 'intensity': {0: 63050,
  1: 63050,
  2: 63050,
  3: 63050,
  4: 63050,
  5: 63050,
  6: 63050,
  7: 63050,
  8: 44600,
  9: 44600,
  10: 63050,
  11: 63050,
  12: 7130,
  13: 7130,
  14: 7130,
  15: 7130,
  16: 63150,
  17: 63150,
  18: 17680,
  19: 17680},
 'eventcount': {0: 1000,
  1: 1000,
  2: 400,
  3: 400,
  4: 200,
  5: 200,
  6: 600,
  7: 600,
  8: 1000,
  9: 1000,
  10: 600,
  11: 600,
  12: 1000,
  13: 1000,
  14: 5000,
  15: 5000,
  16: 400,
  17: 400,
  18: 1000,
  19: 1000}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Comment: Please provide the input and expected output

Comment: Here is the sample recording [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/a4sl1g8rr439f6p/recording.hdf5/file)

Comment: @user3691191 you will have a higher chance of getting useful feedback if you post your data as a small copy-pasteble table as opposed to a link.